# Java LinkedList on displaying Data

Tags: java, linked-list

I have created an inventory management app where the user will be able to add, view and delete data from the inventory. When the user type A, the program will prompt user to enter data. If the user type D, the program will display the data in the inventory. I use LinkedList to achieve this. Im quite new to this. I was able to prompt user to enter data but was not able to display it. Theres a red line on the code. Where did I went wrong? I am sorry if the way I ask is wrong. Do correct me.

Main.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int t = 0;

        LinkedList myList = new LinkedList();

        while(t != 1)
        {
            System.out.print("I, A, D");
            char input = sc.next().charAt(0);


            if(input == 'A')
            {
                System.out.print("Please enter item id: ");
                int id = sc.nextInt();
                sc.nextLine();

                System.out.print("Please enter item name: ");
                String name = sc.nextLine();

                System.out.print("Please enter item type: ");
                String type = sc.nextLine();

                System.out.print("Please enter item price: ");
                double price = sc.nextDouble();
                sc.nextLine();

                Item I1 = new Item(id, name, type, price);
                myList.addItemToFront(I1);
            }

            else if(input == 'D')
            {
                myList.DisplayItem(); //at this point, theres red line which i dont know why?
            }
        }
```

---

LinkedList.java

```
class LinkedList {

    private Node head;  // first node in the linked list
    private int count;

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public Node getHead() {
        return head;
    }

    public LinkedList() {
        head = null;    // creates an empty linked list
        count = 0;
    }

    public void addFront(int n) {
        Node newNode = new Node(n);

        newNode.setLink(head);
        head = newNode;

        count++;
    }

    public void deleteFront() {
        if (count > 0) {
            head = head.getLink();
            count--;
        }
    }

    public void addItemToFront(Item I1)
    {
        Node itemNode = new Node(I1);
        itemNode.setLink(head);
        head = itemNode;
    }

    public void DisplayItem(Node head)
    {
        if(head == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Node current = head;

        while (current != null)
        {
            System.out.println(current.data.toString());
            current = current.getLink();
        }

        System.out.println(current);
    }

    public int length(Node head)
    {
        if(head == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        int count = 0;
        Node current = head;
        while(current != null)
        {
            count++;
            current = current.getLink();
        }
        return count;
    }
```

---

Node.java

```
public class Node {

    Object data;
    private Node link;

    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Node getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(Node link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public Node(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.link = null;
    }
}
```

---

Sample output (How the program should run example)

```
I, A, D

A

Please enter item id: 001

Please enter item name: Wooden Chair

Please enter item type: Furniture

Please enter item price: 50.30

I, A, D

D

001, Wooden Chair, Furniture, 50.30
```

Comment: "_but was not able to display it_" - would help if you fully described the input and expected output.

Comment: I am sorry. Quite new to this. Ive edited the post accordingly.

Comment: You might want to also post up the Node class as well. And also a suggested practice is to Make the LinkedList class Generic for type safety by doing the following

`class LinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>>`

and making the Node class more generic.

Comment: @J.Lee not sure why the elements of a `LinkedList` need to be `Comparable`. That would seem to be conflating concerns.

Comment: Its not necessary, but it helps when you need to delete a certain element from the linked list by checking for that value. Lets say if i want to delete the number 10 from a linked list of integers. `linkedList.remove(10)`, having access to the `compareTo(T data)` helps in my opinion. But I agree with you in the fact that it doesn't necessarily have to be `Comparable`

Comment: @J.Lee **not at all**. That's what `equals` is for. Whilst it is recommended that `compareTo` is "_consistent with `equals`_" it is not required, so using `compareTo` to decide on element removal needs to be explicitly part of the `Collection` contract and having that on a `Collection` which isn't sorted is just ... odd.

Comment: @BoristheSpider fair point. I forgot that we aren't implementing the list interface. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: @J.Lee Ok Sorry. Ive edited the post accordingly.

Comment: @HakimBajuri : What is this I for? :) Also I think there are compile time errors with your code. Please correct them. e.g. DisplayItem method.

Comment: @IfOnly I is for delete the item in the inventory which I've yet to come out with because If i can add and display item correctly, then I'll do the delete function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void DisplayItem() {
    if (head == null) {
        return;
    }

    Node current = head;

    while (current != null) {
        System.out.println(current.getNodeItem().toString());
        current = current.getLink();
    }
}
```

Use this method

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! Yes it works. Appreciate it alot!

Answer (score 0):

As I see your delete method in LinkedList.java class is expecting the Node head to be passed to it before it can iterate. You need to pass the head node to your display method then. 
 I would expect it to be a Compiler error in your Main.java if you have put the right code above.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake. Can you explain to me why does this matter? I thought method is just what the main will retrieve without considering the placement of the code? Your advice will definitely help me.

Comment: There can be many Overloaded method in a java class, for example the DisplayItem(), DisplayItem(Node head), DisplayItem(Node head, String toAppend) etc.  JVM has to know exactly what do you want to be called from Client code - and hence the signature of a method matters. Hope this makes things clearer for you.

Answer (score 0):

The display method in your linked list class accepts an argument of type node which is the head. you need to pass that argument from the main method, then it will work.
Instead of : myList.DisplayItem();
Do this : myList.DisplayItem(head);
Now, if we llok at your LinkedList class, you have made the 'head' as a private variable, either make it public, so that you can access it from the Main class or you can remove the argument from the DisplayItem(Node head) method because any ways you are using the head as a global variable and then iterating over it in the DisplayItem method.
So, better remove the argument from the method definition, it will work.

Comment: no need to pass any parameter to DisplayItem. LinkedList object has head value and DisplayItem can access that directly.

Comment: Ok. I got what you mean. But it still gave me a red line when i add in head. It ask me I should create the variable head which i don't understand why? Shouldn't the head retrieve from linked list? Am I missing something.

Comment: @HakimBajuri : What issue you are facing exactly? at which line. I see only DisplayItem function issue.

Comment: @IfOnly Ok. Sorry for the confusion. I would like to display item from the linked list where i type it at the main.java.                                                                  else if(input == 'D')
            {
                myList.DisplayItem(head);
            }                                                                                                              But I dont get it why theres red underline under the head? Do I need to declare it?

Comment: @HakimBajuri : head variable is not part of your maine object. Its a local variable of LinkedList object, where you have wrote your DisplayItem method. Your dont need to pass parameter to this method. You can directly access head variable.Please see modified DisplayItem methos below.  I hope this is clear.